# How can i multiply these two values one value is from textview and another value from edittext..?

Tags: android

```
    Double  x=Double.parseDouble(textview.getText().toString());
    Double  y=Double.parseDouble(edittext.getText().toString());
    Double  z=x*y;

    finalcost=z+costofevents;
```

or is their any new way to find two value and add to finalcost object

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have (except lacking error checking)?

Comment: Please post the error

Answer (score 1):

If `Double.parseDouble(...)` is what causing problem then try converting **String** to **Double** like

```
Double.valueOf(textview.getText().toString());
```

**Edit:**

Also make sure you have declared your `TextView` and `EditText` properly.

Comment: no difference. Double.valueOf calls parseDouble internally and throws exactly same exception

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: NullPointerException if the string is null.
NumberFormatException if the string does not contain a parsable double.

Comment: @Funkystein Wrong: the answer you posted is talking about `Double.valueOf(double)` while I talk here about `Double.valueOf(String)` which calls `Double.parseDouble(String)` internally. Please check the sources if you like

Comment: btw @Funkystein answer is about Double.valueOf(String) (Correction)

Comment: @Shahzeb In facts, the link i posted has this title: `What is difference between Double.parseDouble(string) and Double.valueOf(string)?` If you and kiruwka would read, before commenting...

Comment: @Funkystein well, if you clicked the links in the answer(or read the accepted answer) you would see that it does talk about `Double.valueOf(double)`. We could also save time if you would just look at the sources. I repeat : `Double.valueOf(String)` calls `Double.parseDouble(String)`.